# Where to set the session timezone (MySql)

Tags: mysql, typeorm

I am using `typeorm` and MySql.

Is there a place I can initialize a statement to set the connection or session `timezone` so that it applies throughout my application?

Or what good way is there to default all times to UTC when I am using a cloud database server without admin privileges? Today I am using GoDaddy, who has set the time zone to MST. If I have to move, the new provider may have a different time zone.

I tried a query `SET timezone='+0:00'` at the `createConnection` callback. It worked, but only for a few minutes. Some time later, queries will return `TIMESTAMP` values in MST. Is it because the database connection gets dropped and is reconnected?

Comment: It doesn't say what driver it uses and it declares both [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) **and** [mysql2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2) as **dev** dependencies (?). It's worth trying adding a `timezone` key to the connection settings.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried that, and found that it does not change the connection `time_zone`. It seems to be using the setting to just interpret the database result. So if I have `timezone` of "Z", even if the server is at MST, typeorm (or is it mysql) will treat the database result (of `TIMESTAMP` type) as UTC that's all.